# Upload file field with multiple tag via php into WordPress media library

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, file-upload

I have a form using a file upload field with a multiple tag. Now I would like to pass it to php via FormData(). This Is what I have tried:

```
<input class="requiredField" type="file" accept=".xls,.xlsx,.csv,.pdf,.msg" name="commitment_publication_communication[]" multiple required>
```

jQuery:

```
var commitment_publication_communication = tool_form_annex.find('input[name="commitment_publication_communication[]"]')[0].files;   
var fd = new FormData();
$.each(commitment_publication_communication, function (i, file) {
   fd.append('c_publication_communication[]', file);
});
```

PhP:

```
$c_publication_communication = $_FILES['c_publication_communication'];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($c_publication_communication); $i++) {
    media_handle_upload('c_publication_communication', 0);
}
```

EDIT: Full Ajax request

```
$.ajax({
   url: ajaxurl,
   type: 'POST',
   processData: false,
   contentType: false,
   data: fd,
   success: function (response) {
        response = JSON.parse(response);
        clickedButton.next().css('display', 'none');
        clickedButtonNext.next().css('display', 'block');
        clickedButtonNext.next().css('color', '#8ed600');
        clickedButtonNext.next().css('margin-top', '20px');
        clickedButtonNext.next().text(devplus_data.successfully_saved_temporarily_message);
        
   },
   error: function () {
        clickedButton.next().css('display', 'none');
        clickedButtonNext.next().css('display', 'block');
        clickedButtonNext.next().css('color', 'red');
        clickedButtonNext.next().css('margin-top', '20px');
        clickedButtonNext.next().text(devplus_data.failed_to_temporarily_save_message);
  }
});
```

I feel like I am going the right way but it's not working.. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: the answer already is given here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicate-values-from-js-array

Comment: You forgot to tell us => what is not working ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping the media_handle_upload function. Also, when I try to return $c_publication_communication, it returns null. So the inputted files did not go through I guess.

Comment: Can you add your ajax jQuery code where you are sending the formData ? the acutual ajax request ?

Comment: try like this => `$c_publication_communication = $_FILES['c_publication_communication'];` you do not need to `[]` in arguments

Comment: only in PHP use this `$c_publication_communication = $_FILES['c_publication_communication']; var_dump($c_publication_communication)`

Comment: in your jQuery code => `var getFiles = $('input[name="commitment_publication_communication[]"]')[0].files
    $.each(getFiles, function (i, file) {
        fd.append('c_publication_communication[]', file);
    });`

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I've made some edits to my question. The jquery now returns an array so that's OK. Now my php loop to handle the upload still doesn't work.

Comment: try the PHP i have provided you - that should show some `var_dump` with array of files from the request - ajax is sending the files.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping when I add var_dump I get the error 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 0' in my console.